# Get attribute of newly created element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the `src` attribute of an image that has been added to the page after it has loaded, but the result keeps coming back `undefined`.

```
$('#qtr').change(function() {
    data = {
        'img': $('#edit_image').attr('src'),
        'degrees': '90'
    };
    $.post('/ajax/ajax_images/rotate', data, function(response) {
        if (response.error != 0) {
            alert('Unable to rotate image');
        }
        else {
            $('#edit_image').attr('src', response.html);
            new_image = response.html;
            var start = new_image.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
            new_image = new_image.substr(start);
        }
    }, 'json');
});​
```

`$('#edit_image')` is the newly created image. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That means the image is not yet loaded. Since you are adding it dyanmically, you should do any process within the `img.onload` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is once the DOM is loaded any modification to your DOM, jquery needs to be  explicitly told about the changes . So use a call back function look in to .bind() or .live() depending on your jquery version.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('img:last' ).attr('src')
```

;-)

Comment: in you case to set a new .src  -->  **$('img:last' ).attr('src', 'newSrc')**